# Lookout security not working

Tags: force-close, lookout

I successfully installed Lookout but when I try to open it it says "Unfortunately Lookout, has stopped. I tried reinstalling it. I can see it running in the notification bar e.g. it says it has finished scanning apps
What can I do to use it?

Comment: Clear cache/data?

Comment: @AlEverett tried

Comment: Look in the Android log and see if the reason for the crash is logged there.

Comment: A reboot might also be worth a try. On one of my devices, two apps seem to regularly require that.

Comment: Since an application update fixed the issue, this seems unlikely to help any future readers.

Comment: @AlEverett ya, go ahead and delete this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the makers and they said it's a known problem and they were working on it. The latest update fixed this.